# How to add days in javascript to fill in missing dates from data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm pretty new to javascript. I'm trying to graph orders by the dates that they were made. I want the graph to contain the days in-between those orders with orders for those dates as 0. How would I add these missing dates in javascript? In my backend, I'm using mongodb aggregate.

```
const dailyOrders = await Order.aggregate([
     {
      $group: {
        _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%m-%d-%Y', date: '$createdAt' } },
        orders: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  ]);
```

Would I have to create a `const` and add it to `createdAt`? I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make mongoDB to return javascript dates not strings. You can use `$dateFromString` (or you can return strings, and convert them to dates in javascript)

`documents=[doc1(has_the_start_date) doc2 ......docn(has_the_end_date)]`

An then you make an array with 1 document for each day, if you have doc for that date in documents you take it from there, else you create an empty doc with that date.

```js
var docIndex=0;
var temp_date=startDate;
var documents_all_dates=[];

while(date<=endDate)
{
  //if i have a document with that date,find out how to compare date day in js
  if(documents[docIndex]["date"] equal temp_date)
  { 
    documents_all_dates.push(documents[docIndex]);
    docIndex++;
  }
  else
  {
    newDoc=...create_document_with_the_date...
    documents_all_dates.push(newDoc);
  }
  temp_date.setDate(temp_date.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Answer is not complete but it might help you.